# Regular Expression syntax in Windows Grep

Tags: windows, grep

How can you do a search in Windows Grep with regular expressions? For example, you have a file which has the following -

**Example File Contents (C:\test\someFile.txt)**

```
void someReallyImportantFunction(void) {
    //do important stuff here
    return;
}
```

**Expected Windows Grep Search Ability**

```
*someReallyImportantFunction(*)*{
```

Here's what I get

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Question**

What is the error in the regular expression here that it sees, the invalid use of a repeat?

I have spent so long debugging, I give in! Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am basing my answer from here : http://www.wingrep.com/Help/html/search-regexp.htm

the asterisk character reporesents 0 or more instances of the preceding character. it seems that you are using as a pure wildcard. I believe the error is that the first asterisk is trying to repeat nothing. So past the error you probably wont get the result you want. I would try '.*' where '.*' is 0 or more of any characters. Depending on how granular you want to be you could check for [a-zA-Z]* or something similar.

Comment: Solution - 'grep .*someReallyImportantFunction\(.*\).*{ /cygdrive/c/test/*'